# Rails won't serve static content on Webrick in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

I have been trying almost everything to get rails/webrick to serve an html file in development mode, however I keep getting the following error:

No route matches [GET] "/public/index.html"

Even after setting **config.assets.enabled = true** nothing changes.
Running Rails 3.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public directory is your root directory from the website perspective. For instance:

```
/path_to_rails/public/index.html = http://localhost:3000/index.html
/path_to_rails/public/subdir/home.html = http://localhost:3000/subdir/home.html
```

This assumes you are running your local dev server at `http://localhost:3000`